# How to tell Spring-Shell to not parse command line arguments as shell commands?

Tags: java, spring-shell

I am using [spring-shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/3.1.5/docs/index.html) to develop a CLI app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@CommandScan
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(App.class);
    application.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
    application.run(args);
  }
```

It was working well until I ran into this problem: when I try to run my app like:

```
java -jar my.jar com.mycompany.App --flag
```

I get following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.shell.CommandNotFound: No command found for '--flag'
        at org.springframework.shell.Shell.evaluate(Shell.java:207) ~[spring-shell-core-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
        at org.springframework.shell.Shell.run(Shell.java:159) ~[spring-shell-core-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
        at org.springframework.shell.jline.NonInteractiveShellRunner.run(NonInteractiveShellRunner.java:146) ~[spring-shell-core-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
        at org.springframework.shell.DefaultShellApplicationRunner.run(DefaultShellApplicationRunner.java:65) ~[spring-shell-core-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
```

It's true there is no command for `--flag`. That is meant to be a startup option not a command that should be interpreted by the shell. (Problem #1).

Another problem is that spring-shell runs in `NonInteractiveShellRunner` as soon as I provide some command line arguments. I want it to run in interactive mode. (Problem #2).

How can I tell it so? I read the docs but could not find solution to this puzzle.

Comment: Please include enough of the exception to actually identify it; the fragment of a stack trace isn't useful

Comment: the rest of the stack frames got omitted but I think the trace pasted in the question is sufficient. I have also added some code that shows what I am doing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure it's sufficient. When I look up the lines listed in that stack trace in Spring's source code, I can't tell if the first argument was consumed to generate the ApplicationRunner instance in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/e4a0e9d9acf90b2f16656e10211b7e72476acad6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L775 or if it's passed through as the first element of the ApplicationArguments, because that decision was made further up the stack.

Comment: (the former is reasonable if we're trying to act like a UNIXy shell, in the "first argument selects the thing to run, subsequent arguments are passed to that thing" sense -- which is certainly what the error message implies)

Comment: Granted, that's trying to figure it out as someone who doesn't know Spring; a person with a better handle on the framework would probably be fine with the context you've provided.

Comment: Isn't what to do described in [Options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/3.1.5/docs/index.html#using-shell-options) or [Single Command](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/3.1.5/docs/index.html#using-shell-customization-singlecommand)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not option in spring-shell to tell it not to parse a command. At least not out of the box. What you can do however is parse the source `String[] args` and create a new argument instance (myArgs) which does not contain the `--flag` parameter and start the application with your modified args `application.run(myArgs)`